# Given $C_p(X)$ where $X$ is Tychonoff and $A \subseteq C_p(X)$. When does the interior of $A$ not empty

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be Tychonoff and $C_p(X)$ the space of continuous real valued functions over $X$ with the topology of pointwise convergence. And suppose that the constant function $f=0$ is in the boundary of $A$. Can I say thet $A$ has a nonempty interior? Or, can I at least say that for every $a \in A$ and an open neighborhood $a \in U$, $U \cap (A \setminus \{a\}) \neq \emptyset$?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to both questions is no.  Consider $C_p ( \mathbb{R} )$, and let $A = \{ z \}$ (where $z$ denotes the constant zero function).  Clearly $z \in \partial A$, but $\mathrm{Int} ( A ) = \varnothing$ and $z$ is not an accumulation point of $A$.  ($\mathbb{R}$ can be replaced by many *many* spaces.)